Is the Mahaganapathi Moola Mantra a Vedic Mantra?
I am referring to the Mahaganapathi Moola Mantra which consists of 28 syllables.
Is the Mahaganapathi Moola Mantra a Vedic Mantra or a Tantric Mantra or a Mantra from the Puranas?
Thank you.
